# Visual Studio 2022 behaving wierdly in C++, not showing errors in code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022

I'm currently learning C++ and encountered a strange behavior of VS. Errors are not showing up in code (even though IntelliSense is enabled - I checked settings) and the lines in error list are probably wrong too.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "fraction.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fraction a = fraction::fraction(2, -4);
    cout << a.toString();
}
```

fraction.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class fraction
{
private:
    int a;
    int b;

    void Optimise()
    {
        if (b < 0)
        {
            a = -a;
            b = -b;
        }

        if (a % b == 0 || b % a == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i <= b; i++)
            {
                if (a % i == 0 && b % i == 0)
                {
                    a /= i;
                    b /= i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public:
    fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        a = numerator;
        if (denominator != 0)
        {
            b = denominator;
        }
        else
        {
            //exception
        }

        Optimise();
    }

    string toString()
    {
        return a + "/" + b;
    }
};
```

Code looks normal in text editor, however it won't compile and it [shows these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC5Dv.png)

Thanks for help! :)

Edit:
The reason was not writing `std::` in front of strings in fraction.h, but VS did not highlight the error, see long answer below.

Comment: I suspect your project is not set up to be using the current C++ standard.  Check your project settings.

Comment: Write `std::string`, not just `string`.

Comment: VS tip: the Error List is almost useless. Go to the Output window and locate the very first error. Fix that first and ignore the rest, then recompile and keep fixing the first error and compile until it's all good. (And don't trust IntelliSense.)

Comment: Ok, I will try that then. But with C# IntelliSense worked great.

Comment: I tried putting this code into a VS C++ project. The errors are shown for me, are you sure that the project is set to C++ (please verify this).

Comment: Yes, the project is set to C++ 14 Standart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the code for not compiling was not writing `std::string` or `using namespace std` at the top in fraction.h as @molbdnilo has pointed out. What confused me, was that VS highlighted the code and knew I ment to write `std::`, but the compiler did not.

Also, I would like to point out my mistake (which has nothing to do with compiler) in my work with strings (since I'm still learning).

Instead of:

```
string toString()
{
    return a + "/" + b;
}
```

Should be:

```
std::string toString()
{
    return std::to_string(a) + "/" + std::to_string(b);
}
```